# How to remove <VALUE> text from legend in layout view?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, legend

I'm producing a map in the layout view which I will eventually export as a jpeg. I've added a legend which includes 15 classes but when I insert a legend in layout view its including the word VALUE at the top of the legend column - I had a look at the properties and can't seem to figure out how to remove this - I'm using ArcMap 10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If i got you there are three options

1. **By Changing Style** As mentioned by PolyGeo just double click on the legend to access legend properties and do as below
   [image: By Changing Style]
2. **By Changing in the TOC** As mentioned by radouxju as below 
   [image: By Changing in the TOC]
3. **By Converting into Graphics** This is the last but not least method where you will find solution if all above do not work. Process is as below
   [image: By Converting into Graphics]

Comment: For the first picture, the order of screencaps are as follows: Middle -> Right -> Left

Answer (score 5):

An easier way is to right click on your Legend and click on "Properties." 
In the Legend's property menu click on the "Items" tab. You'll be able to see the contents that are within your Legend. [image]

Then right click on any of the contents you want to change and select "Properties"
[image]
Now just uncheck "Show Layers Name" and "Show Heading."
Click ok and you're done. 
I find this to be the best way for me as I don't have to convert the Legend to graphics and disconnect it from my "Table of Contents."

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you open the **Legend Properties** to the **Items** tab and then select the layer with that classification.

When you click **Style** you will open the **Legend Item Selector** where you have a choice of about 12 presentation styles and I suspect that if you watch the **Preview** as you try each you will soon find one that suits your purpose.

If not, I recommend that you edit your Question to provide detailed step by step instructions for how you classified your layer, and then generated your legend.

This is described in the help document entitled **[Working with legends](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s900000023000000.htm)**.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick fix to this issue is to delete the word value in the table of content.

Another workaround consists in converting your legend into graphic element, ungroup then delete the parts that you don't want (but then you lose all link with the table of content, so you should do a maximum using the table of content and only convert to graphics for final "tuning" of the legend display).

Answer (score 0):

1. RIGHT click on the legend and go to PROPERTIES
2. ITEMS tab - select the item in the left-hand side, and check OFF the box next to "Only show classes that are visible in the current map extent".
3. Click Apply and OK.

This will remove the < VALUE> in the legend

Found this in ARCGIS 10.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what that is the Heading label from the Symbology tap of the layer properties. In my example it says DESCRIPTION and not Values like in yours. Its the same thing, just that my value field for the label category is different. Simply delete the whole word out and ok.[image]